# Is there any way to find out what is the nth character in a string using python?

Tags: python

I'm making a currency converter in python and I would like to be able to find what the first character in a string is. By this I mean so if the user inputs the string "$32" my program can take out the first character, being "$", and recognise that the user would like to convert from dollars.

I'm sure this is possible in python but I cant figure out for the life of me how to do it, any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I suggest that you use a `dictionary` to store conversion values instead of using countless `if/elif` statements

Answer (score 2):

Hope to be helpful for you. You can use `val` as number.

```
string = "$32"
first = string[0]
val = int(string[1:])
print(first, val)
```

Comment: this solution cannot handle decimals, try float() instead of int()

Answer (score 1):

In general the way to acess the nth character in a string is like this:

```py
character = string[n]
```

So in your example use this:

```py
string = "$32"
dollar = string[0]
three = string[1]
two = string[2]
```

Note that we start counting at 0.

Comment: This code contains errors. `str` is a function, while `string` is the variable. Also, it's hardcoded and won't work to convert the numbers to integers.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me I made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution was the use of slicing.

```
s = '$45'
curr, value = s[0], float(s[1:])
```

but I suggest to adopt some specific library to tackle with all combinations like [price parser](https://pypi.org/project/price-parser/).

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
actual = "$32"
value = float(actual[1:])
if actual[0] == "$":
    #do the converstion
```